# session gives null value with process.start() in asp.net ? why

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, popup

i have stored value in session and start a process to navigate to another page 
cookies are disabled

here is a code to store session and process

```
    HttpContext.Current.Session["url"] = url;

   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://localhost:50660/SearcResult.aspx");
```

in another page i have to get session stored value because with response redirect i am facing popup problem so here in page load of new form that is SearchResult.aspx

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string session = Convert.ToString(Session["url"]);
        //if (session != "")
        //{
            string link = Convert.ToString(Session["url"]);
            frame.InnerHtml = (" <iframe class='ifr' src='" + link + "' > </iframe>");
        //}
        //else {

        //    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");



        //}
    }
```

> but the session value is NULL

### need help i want to navigate to another page with session have url with out facing popup problem

Comment: i am using  disable cookies

Comment: What are you doing with Process.Start in an ASP.Net application? Your comment to the answer below needs clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Response.Redirect` instead of `process`.

```
Response.Redirect("http://localhost:50660/SearcResult.aspx");
```

Comment: i am using static method so using   'HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://localhost:50660/SearcResult.aspx");  cannot redirect to other page and function even not reach return "url"' so give 500 internal error